# how to publish a combine string of list values to a message box

Tags: c#, list, export

I have a while loop that publishes certain values into a string, and i a button which should join the values into a string and show that as a message box.

```
string toDisplay = string.Join("," , Export.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(toDisplay);
```

However all i get is the internal list not the values.
 [export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGwNe.png)

the list initiator

```
List<int> Export = new List<int>();
```

Comment: If Export is a List of strings then you don't add ToString() in the Join, leave the list alone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Export is a List of int then you don't add ToString() in the Join, just leave the list alone

```
string toDisplay = string.Join("," , Export);
MessageBox.Show(toDisplay);
```

If you add the *ToString()* method to *Export* variable you are asking the list to give a representation of itself as a string, but the generic `List<T>` doesn't have any override for that and use the underlying *ToString()* from the base *object* class. This method just outputs the class name.
Instead if you leave just the List variable name *Export* then the Join method used is the one that enumerate the list elements (integers) and ask them one by one to give a ToString() representation of themselves. Integers can do that.

Answer (score 0):

It's good to know also some Linq, `Aggregate` can help:

```
var toDisplay = (export?.Any() ?? false) ? // not null and not empty
                export.Select(m => m.ToString()).Aggregate((m1, m2) => $"{m1},{m2}") : 
                string.Empty;
```

**Note:** But @Steve answer is more efficient from memory allocation point of view